# Enumerate inside a string

Tags: ruby, string, enumeration, string-interpolation

I'm trying to enumerate an array inside a string, and have the values of the array interpolate inside of string.

Example:

```
todos = ["sleep", "eat", "powernap"]

"Today I have todo: \n" +
'#{todos.each do |todo| }'
"\t #{todo}" +
'#{end}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
"Today I have todo: \n\tsleep\neat\npowernap"
```

Comment: `"Today I have todo: \n\t#{todos.join("\n")}"`

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly; exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting `#{...}` to work like ERB's `<%...%>` or even PHP's `<?php` but that's not the case. The string interpolation must contain a complete, syntactically valid Ruby expression, and that bit of code is incomplete.

You can rework that to be a singular expression:

```
"Today I have todo: #{todos.join("\t "}"
```

Or you can do your iteration manually, though this is often sub-optimal in terms of performance:

```
todos.each_with_object("Today I have todo:") do |todo, buffer|
  buffer << "\t " << todo
end
```

As you can see the first version is significantly more concise.

Ruby's string interpolation options are unusually flexible, but they do require the code to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this:

```
Today I have todo:
        sleep
        eat
        powernap
```

To do this you can use a [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-map) to wrap each element in a tab and newline, then [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-join) to turn the strings in the Array into a single string.

```
todos.map {|todo| "\t#{todo}\n"}.join("")
```

That will put a newline and tab around each element, and then concatenate each element together. Note that it's using the concatenation by using `#{}` to embed a variable in the string. It also could have been `"\t" + todo + "\n"`, that is exactly the same.

The result is:

```
"\tsleep\n\teat\n\tpowernap\n"
```

Then you can concatenate that with the string, nothing special is needed.

```
puts "Today I have todo:\n" +
     todos.map {|todo| "\t#{todo}\n"}.join("") +
     "I hope I get them done!\n"
```

There's lots of ways to do it, but the important thing is it has to produce a String. `each` won't work because it will produce an Array and you'll get something like this:

```
Today I have todo:
    ["sleep", "eat", "powernap"]
I hope I get them done!
```

If you want to, you could do this as string interpolation by putting the whole expression into a `#{}` inside the string. Here's a simpler example that turns the list into a comma-separated string.

```
puts "Today I have todo: #{todos.join(", ")}\n"
```

Any expression can go into `#{}`, but `#{}` must contain a complete expression! Each `#{}` will be run on its own and each result will be concatenated into the string.